# Creating MySQL query with MyBB to explode a field storing a string

Tags: php, mysql, substring, mybb

I am currently working with a MyBB set up where I am trying to do an SQL query which can check if a user is part of a certain additional group. However, I am having difficulties.

MyBB stores additional group IDs in one VARCHAR field separated by commas, such as 1,23,27,30,49 etc. I know that in PHP I can explode strings using the comma as a delimiter. I understand that MySQL cannot explode, but I can use substring_index to achieve a similar goal. Point to note each user could have a random list of additional groups, so not all users would be the same.

I am trying this

```
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT username, additionalgroups FROM my_users WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(30, ',', 1)');
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    print '<div class="name"><a href="#">' . $row['username'] . '</a></div>';
}
```

This does not seem to work though. Looking at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index I seem to be following their way of constructing the condition, but I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer in E:\xampp\htdocs\11thinfantrybrigade.co.uk\orbat.php:180 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\11thinfantrybrigade.co.uk\orbat.php(180): PDO->query('SELECT username...', ', 1)') #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\11thinfantrybrigade.co.uk\orbat.php on line 180

Any advice please?

The end goal is to print a list of users that meet that criteria.

Thank you.

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX first argument must be a string, you have '30'. You supply no field to the function, very odd?

Also: it is not clear what you want to do: find all users in group 30? If that is what you want that is much easier: `SELECT username FROM my_users WHERE CONCAT(',',additionalgroups,',') LIKE "%,30,%"`

Comment: Hi Roemer, thank you. I thought as the additionalgroups field is a varchar, 30 would classify as a string. Is this not the case? When you say I have supplied no field to the function, do you mean I should add something like my_users.additionalgroups into the query? I completely over looked the fact I supplied no field - thank you.

Comment: You would help us if you told us what exactly you want to accomplish. What does all of this code need to do? Are you listing all users that have nr 30 in the comma separated field additionalgroups? (If yes, I answered that,)

Comment: I did say what I wanted to do. I stated I wanted to print a list of users that meet that criteria; the criteria being 30 in the additional groups list.

I appreciate you sent an answer, but I have tried it, and I still receive a similar error:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer in E:\xampp\htdocs\11thinfantrybrigade.co.uk\orbat.php:181 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\11thinfantrybrigade.co.uk\orbat.php(181): PDO->query('SELECT username...', ',additionalgrou...', ') LIKE "%,30,%"') #1 {main} thrown in E:\...\orbat.php on line 181

Comment: Like NewBee said: always escape the quotes. You cannot have the same quotes within quotes. Because this is sort of lesson 1 in PHP I did not think I had to explain that ;)  You can read some of the necessary basic string skills in php here: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT username FROM my_users WHERE CONCAT(",",additionalgroups,",") LIKE "%,30,%"' ; 

$stmt = $conn->query($query);
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    print '<div class="name"><a href="#">' . $row['username'] . '</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Roemer, I did escape the quotes as NewBee shown, but I still received the error. I didn't think to just change the type of quotation marks. It now works. 

Thank you kindly for helping and putting up with my tired newbness!

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT username, additionalgroups FROM my_users WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(\'30\', \',\', 1)');
```

Preferably it should be like this as the `,` outside the quotes will cause trouble to PHP.

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the error and displays an output, however , it displays all users now. I imagine this might be down to what @Roemer said about not supplying a field.